# why SVM obtain different result using different feature?

Tags: svm, tf-idf

I used SVM for classification. and also I apply TF, TFIDF and present-absent as a feature. but I got different result. now I want to know how this happen?
How can I examine the reason of this result?
I should mention that this difference is not too high. it is about 2 or 3 percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - because **every** machine learning method **depends** on the **representation**. In particular, it is true that for any reasonable (able to learn linearly separable data) classifier there exists data representation which results in this classifier having 50% accuracy (random classifier, assuming that classes are balanced) and there exists a data representation which results in classifier having 100% accuracy (asuming zero Bayes risk). Consider a "feature set" {f(x)}, where f(x)=0. In other words we represent each data point as a single number 0, ignoring its true position and label. As a result any classifier will fail and classify all of them as a members of one class and so get 50% of accuracy (assuming again, equal numberof samples in each class). Now consider {g(x)} where g(x)=label(x). In other words we use some hypothethical oracle, which encodes a point as its label. In general we cannot construct such g (this is what ML is all about), but we are talking about existance, and this for sure, exists (assuming zero Bayes risk). So now our classifier has to distinguish point {-1} from point {1} (ass all positive samples are mapped to +1 and all negative ones to -1) which is trivial and it will do it with 100% accuracy.

These are "border" cases, but it is just to draw an intuition. **Everything** depends on the representation. One can be better (in some aspects!) than other. There are no strict rules. Sometimes adding new features to a good representation may destroy its value (due to for example curse of dimensionality) and sometimes even random features perform great. There is a whole (very active these years) field of study called **Representation learning** I suggest you take a look at that.